# Unable to work with font-awesome offline, fonts are not been shown

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, font-awesome

I want to make my font awesome working for our intranet application (Offline), so i follow this link @ https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself, where i did the following:-

1) I download the package:-

[image]

2) and i added the `all.css` + `webfonts` inside our root folder as follow:-

[image]

then i added this link to the all.css inside the head as follow:-

```
<link href="~/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but i did not get any of the fonts inside my application? any advice?

Here is part of the `all.min.css`:-

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Free 5.13.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
 */
.fa,
.fas,
.far,
.fal,
.fad,
.fab {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1; }

.fa-lg {
  font-size: 1.33333em;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  vertical-align: -.0667em; }

.fa-xs {
  font-size: .75em; }

.fa-sm {
  font-size: .875em; }

.fa-1x {
  font-size: 1em; }

.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em; }

.fa-3x {
  font-size: 3em; }

.fa-4x {
  font-size: 4em; }

.fa-5x {
  font-size: 5em; }

.fa-6x {
  font-size: 6em; }

.fa-7x {
  font-size: 7em; }

.fa-8x {
  font-size: 8em; }

.fa-9x {
  font-size: 9em; }

.fa-10x {
  font-size: 10em; }

.fa-fw {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.25em; }

.fa-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 0; }
  .fa-ul > li {
    position: relative; }

.fa-li {
  left: -2em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: inherit; }

.fa-border {
  border: solid 0.08em #eee;
  border-radius: .1em;
  padding: .2em .25em .15em; }

.fa-pull-left {
  float: left; }

.fa-pull-right {
  float: right; }

.fa.fa-pull-left,
.fas.fa-pull-left,
.far.fa-pull-left,
.fal.fa-pull-left,
.fab.fa-pull-left {
  margin-right: .3em; }

.fa.fa-pull-right,
.fas.fa-pull-right,
.far.fa-pull-right,
.fal.fa-pull-right,
.fab.fa-pull-right {
  margin-left: .3em; }

.fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
          animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear; }

.fa-pulse {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(8);
          animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(8); }

@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg); } }

@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg); } }

.fa-rotate-90 {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg); }

.fa-rotate-180 {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `.woff` and `.woff2` to MIME types in your web hosting,
- or you can try this in startup:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ServeUnknownFileTypes = true });
```

- or you can specify the file extension to be served as below:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    // Add new mappings
    provider.Mappings[".woff"] = "font/woff";
    provider.Mappings[".woff2"] = "font/woff2";

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = provider
    });
}
```

references:

- [FileExtensionContentTypeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider)
- [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

---

Another possible issue could be the path problem. I've [downloaded the package](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web.zip) and extracted it under `wwwroot` folder, then renamed it to **fontawesome** just for easy access.

[image: wwwroot folder structure]

Then added the `all.css` file as below:

```html
<link href="~/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and everything worked fine. Notice that you have a different folder structure under your `wwwwroot`!

Comment: i added the following to the startup.cs file `var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings[".woff"] = "font/woff";
            provider.Mappings[".woff2"] = "font/woff2";

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });` but still i did not get the icons working.. not sure what is going on... also the console is not showing any errors..

Comment: @testtest I've updated my answer to show how I did it.

Comment: ok it worked now, i thought i only need to include the `webfonts`

Answer (score 0):

Are the fonts specified in the css? Like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

Comment: the font are specified as follow `.fa-angle-double-right:before {
  content: "\f101"; }
`

Comment: I would try it with using font-face and then specifying the font in each css class

Comment: can you advice more on this?